# event triggers vs callback in options

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

In jQuery plugins, which way do you think it's best to allow a function to be hooked in your plugin - trough triggers, or options (arguments) passed in the plugin function?

`$.trigger('myplugin_completed', someData);`

`$(document).bind('myplugin_completed', function(event, someData){ ... });`

vs

`myPluginOptions.onComplete(someData);`

`$('.stuff').myPlugin({onComplete: function(someData){ ... }});`

Comment: You can use plugin namespaces like this: `$('#div').on('click.myplugin')`, which is good for keeping method names clean.

Comment: ...and be able to unbind all events added by the plugin at once

Comment: @DidierGhys: Good point, this is a lot simpler.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Solution

I think the best solution - at least in the case you described (maybe not in all the possible cases) - is to combine both in the following way:

```
$('.stuff').myPlugin(/* some options here */);
$('.stuff').trigger('myplugin.completed', someData);
```

and this line:

```
$('.stuff').on('myplugin.completed', function(event, someData){
    /* callback code */
});
```

is responsible for binding the event handler. It can be called also when someone passes `onComplete` callback within options when initializing your plugin (of course selector should be adjusted to meet the one used by the code initializing your pugin).

### Summary

To sum up, you could:

- create your own event (`completed`),
- use your plugin's namespace for this event / plugin (in this case `myplugin`),
- use `.on()` function (available and preferred since jQuery 1.7),
- if `onComplete` option is passed to your plugin, there is no problem in binding it within the code initializing the plugin (so from within the plugin, using the `.on()` function, binding event handler to your event name within your even namespace).

Answer (score 2):

**I will vote for the second** option, because in this way one can control the onComplete event, and it is binded only to the element. Binding it to documents it is not good, because one can do $(document).unbind(), that unbind all events.

Answer (score 1):

I think both ways are good and none of them has big advantage over another.

For example, jQuery UI use callback for options and event triggers for actual events such as start/stop dragging.

But, by creating event triggers in code you create maybe more flexible way to add more event handlers, without modyfing existing code. I mean when you got callbacks, it goes this way:

```
{onComplete: function(someData){ action_1; }}
```

If you need some extra actions you write them into existion function or put functions inside:

```
{onComplete: function(){  action_1; action_2 }}
```

or

```
{onComplete: function(){  action_1; function_2(); }}

function_2(){ action_2 };
```

For comparison using events it would be like:

```
$('selector').on('myplugin_completed.myplugin', function_1 })
```

Extra actions:

```
$('selector').on('myplugin_completed.myplugin_extra', function_2 })
```

If you don't need some actions you can unbind only them.

```
$('selector').off('myplugin_completed.myplugin_extra');
```

There are differences between them, but usually it depends on particular situation, which one is better;